# Find common character in a string

Tags: c, string, function

Hi i have two different string and i need to find the common character in the string. I managed to get the common string but i need to return "null string" for input that does not have same character.

Current issues:

input1: abc
input2: def
output: '  // it shld be "null string";

heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strInterset(char * str1, char * str2, char * str3);

int main() {
    char str1[50], str2[50], str3[50];

    printf("Enter str1: \n");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    printf("Enter str2: \n");
    scanf("%s", str2);
    strInterset(str1, str2, str3);

    if (*str3 == '\0')
        printf("strIntersect(): null string\n");
    else
        printf("strIntersect(): %s\n", str3);

    return 0;
}

void strInterset(char * str1, char * str2, char * str3) {
    int i = 0, j;
    for (i; *(str1 + i) != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; *(str2 + j) != '\0'; j++) {
            if ( *(str2 + j) == *(str1 + i)) {
                strcpy(str3, str1 + i);
                str3++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with the above code? Initialise str3[50] to null

Comment: If there are no common characters `str3` is an unintialised variable with indeterminate value(s).

Comment: Even if there are common characters, `str3` won't be NUL terminated

Comment: @ChrisTurner `strcpy` copies the nul terminator.

Comment: sorry what i meant was the output should be "null string"

Comment: @WeatherVane ah, yeah - missed it was doing a `strcpy` cos it is doing `str3++` which doesn't make sense if it's copying multiple characters

Comment: @ChrisTurner agreed, the algorithm is not great. Will only work properly if the last character is common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `strInterset()` only calls `strcpy()` if a match is found, and doesn't modify `str3` or the data it points to otherwise.   The fix is simple - before the loop in `strInterset()` add the statement

```
 *str3 = '\0';
```

If a match is found,  `strcpy()` will still be called.   If not, the test being done in `main()` will succeed.

Initialising the array in `main()` to zero will also work for the FIRST call of `strInterset()`.   It may not work for subsequent calls though (unless `main()` reinitialises `str3` before every call).   Hence it is better to do the initialisation in `strInterset()`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your `str3` explictly to NULL by declaring it like

```
char str3[50] = { NULL };
```

If you do not do that its an unitialised array with junk/indeterminate values.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `str3` to `NULL`, like this:

```
char str3[50] = {0};
```

since if you don't do that, it will remain an unitialized array, which means that it will invoke *Undefined Behavior* when accessed, since its values are garbage.

Moreover, even if common character(s) exist, `str3` will not be NULL-terminated.

I would personally change your function to this:

```
void strInterset(char * str1, char * str2, char * str3) {
    int i = 0, j;
    *str3 = '\0'; // NULL terminate
    for (i; *(str1 + i) != '\0'; i++) {
        ...
}
```

Output:

```
Enter str1: abc
Enter str2: dfg
strIntersect(): null string
```

---

PS: Compile with warnings enabled and you will get:

```
prog.c: In function 'strInterset':
prog.c:26:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     for (i; *(str1 + i) != '\0'; i++) {
     ^~~
```

Just change it to: `for (; *(str1 + i) != '\0'; i++) {`, or even better `for (int i = 0; *(str1 + i) != '\0'; i++) {`. This is not your problem, but is good to fix warnings.

Comment: Oops, missed that @PeterJ_01, thanks! How does it look now?

Comment: sorry what i meant was that the output sjould display "null string" not null character

Comment: It will output `strIntersect(): null string` in case no common character(s) is found @Denise.

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix should be `str3[0] = '\0'` as second line in `main`.

But there are more ways you can make your program better:

- Why you need a full `char str3[50]`? You could instead use the return value of the function like this: `char strInterset(char * str1, char * str2);` And then add `return` in the appropriate places. (By the way: should that be spellect `intersect`?)
- Your program uses two nested `for`-loops (which is slow on large inputs). Instead, you could make an array where each entry corresponds to one character value (look at an ascii-table). The array then can contain a true/false whether the character appeared. You initialize all entries to 0. Then you run through the first string and for each character you set its entry in the array to 1. Then you run through the second string and for each character you check whether the entry in the array *is* 1. If such a case is found then you found a character that appears in both strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your function which checks for the common characters and adds them to the result string without the repetition. If you do not care about the repetitions just remove the second if (and only the line where the if is, but leave its body in the brackets )

```
char *strcomm(const char *s1, const char *s2, char *s3)
{
    const char *tmp;
    char *tmps3 = s3;
    *s3 = 0;
    while(*s1)
    {
        tmp = s2;
        while(*tmp)
        {
            if(*s1 == *tmp)
                if(strchr(s3,*s1) == NULL)
                {
                    *s3++ = *s1;
                    *s3 = 0;
                }
            tmp++;
        }
        s1++;
    }
    return tmps3;
}
```